# how to get numerically flowing numbers for each page in a datagridview using string arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, datagridview

I have a string array with over 1000 items and I have split it in 4 separate arrays. I am trying to put them on a `datagridview` in numerical order each column can hold 28 items and there are four columns on each page.

Each page should look something like this:

```
column 1 1-28
column 2 29-56
column 3 57-84
column 4 85-112
```

this would be page 1. Page 2 would start with number 113 on column 1.

Currently I have already put the string arrays in the `datagridview` but the numbers don't flow correctly in each page but it flows correctly going straight down.

Splitting large array to four parts:

```
string[] array = new string[listBox1.Items.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    array[i] = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();
}

string[] array2 = array.Take((array.Length / 2).ToArray();
string[] array3 = array.Skip((array.Length / 2).ToArray();

string[] array4 = array2.Take((array2.Length + 1) / 2).ToArray();
string[] array5 = array2.Skip((array2.Length + 1) / 2).ToArray();

string[] array6 = array3.Take((array3.Length + 1) / 2).ToArray();
string[] array7 = array3.Skip((array3.Length + 1) / 2).ToArray();
```

Adding the arrays to the `datagridview`:

```
string a = "";
for (int i = 0; i < array4.Length; i++)
{
    addData(array4[i], a, array5[i], a, array6[i],a, array7[i],a );
}
```

Function to add data to `datagrid`

```
private void addData(string a, string b, string c, string d, string e, string f, string g, string h)
{
    string[] row = { a, b, c, d,e,f,g,h };
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

The result I would want is to have numerically flowing numbers on each page.

Comment: When I read your code it seems your logic is correct. `but the numbers don't flow correctly in each page but it flows correctly going straight down`. Could you please show us an example or an image of output?

Comment: hello over here is a sample image https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eNdQW__pByiRtoGRnhgdeetMVNY4mX48

Comment: Thank you for providing sample output. It seems if you sort `string[] array` before splitting it into 4 arrays you get desired output. Try `Array.Sort(array);` before splitting it.

Comment: i got it working with the code below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following puts numbers into a DataTable. You can make the table the `datagridview1.DataSource = dt;`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //create a 1000 strings from numbers starting at 1001
            string[] array = Enumerable.Range(1001, 1000).Select(x => "String : " + x.ToString()).ToArray();

            var pages = array.Select((x,i) => new {str = x, index = i})
                .GroupBy(x => x.index  / 112)
                .Select(x => x.ToArray())
                .ToArray();

            var rows = pages
                .SelectMany(x => x.GroupBy(y => y.index % 28)).Select(y => y.ToArray())
                .ToArray();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Col A", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Col B", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Col C", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Col D", typeof(string));


            foreach (var row in rows)
            {
                DataRow newRow = dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 
                    row[0].str, 
                    (row.Length > 1) ? (object)row[1].str : null,
                    (row.Length > 2) ? (object)row[2].str : null,
                    (row.Length > 3) ? (object)row[3].str : null
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```